# How to override default values of a vuejs component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've implemented a VUEJS plugin (via CDN) and it works, but I cannot change the default props.. any idea how to change the defaults?

In the code below you can see my attempt to accomplish this

html:

```html
<tags-dic element-id="tags" v-model="selectedTags" :typeahead="true"></tags-input>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@voerro/vue-tagsinput@1.11.2/dist/voerro-vue-tagsinput.js"></script>
```

vue/javascript:

```java
<script type="text/javascript">

            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#searchapp',
                components: {  "tags-dic": VoerroTagsInput },

                data: {
                    query: "",
                    typeahead: true,
                    placeholder: 'Add a new tag',
                    limit: 1,
                    onlyExistingTags: true,
                    existingTags: [
                         'DNA',
                         'RNA',
                         'Protein',
                                ],
                    selectedTags: [], 

                },
                methods: {
                    submit: function() {
                        console.log("clicked");
                        if (this.query) {

                            console.log("OK");

                        }
                    }
                }
            })


        </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Changed the name of the question since `vue-tagsinput` is a component, not a plugin

Comment: And which default properties are you trying to change? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: attempting to change the props, as seen in the example (e.g. placeholder, typeahead..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply your own property values in the template. (See the [docs](https://github.com/voerro/vue-tagsinput) for details.)

```
<tags-dic 
    element-id="tags" 
    v-model="selectedTags" 
    :typeahead="true"
    :existing-tags="existingTags"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
/>
```

and so on